# Z-transform of a function in R language

Tags: r, matlab, signal-processing

I have a function f(x) that gives me results in time domain. I want to get the z-transform of that function so that I can compare both. I know this would be easy to calculate in MATLAB. However, I'm wondering if there is a way to do it in R by a package or writing a code from scratch. The reason for using R because I have done most of the required work and other calculations in R.(Plus R is free)

I searched and found some suggestions to use `scale`. However, I think it has to do with data not the function. Also, I found a package `GeneNet` which has a function called z-transform. However, it gives a vector of numbers. I want to get the z-transform as function of z.

By definition z-transform calculated from :
[image]

Update for simplicity:
if we have `f(x)= x, where x= 0,1,2,3,4,....100.` I want to get the z-transform for the given function f(x).

Based on the above definition of z-transform and by substitution:

```
   x(z) = SUM from n=0 to n=100 of (Xn) *(Z ^-n)
```

`for n=0 => x(z)= (0) (Z^-0)`

`for n=1 => x(z)= 0 + (1) (z^-1)`

`for n=2 => x(z)= 0 + (1) (z^-1) + (2) (z^-2)`

`...`

`..`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I am sure there is a way to do this in R if its easy to code into Matlab. Have you tried using dataframes?

Comment: In Matlab they have built-in function. No I haven't , and I'm not really sure if it's doable as we need to have the variable z in the summation !

Comment: The suggestion to use `scale` is a confusion of terminology - as R is mostly used for statistics whoever made that assumed you were calculating a [z-score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score). This should be easy in R but I'm having trouble matching your z-transform definition which uses x, z, and n, to your little R code, which uses f(t), t, and y. It seems like maybe `y` is `x_i` and is always 16, and `t = 0:100` is equivalent to `n`? What does `f(t) = t XOR y` have to do with anything?

Comment: I agree, the definition in a general form, t is equivalent to n and x of n is equivalent f(t). Y is always a constant value= 16. I will update the question.

Comment: Chirp's z-transform is directly related to fast Fourier transformations, for which there is a package `fft`. Can you get that to work for this purpose?

Comment: @Ken. I will try fft. didn't know about it !

Comment: The link to matlab ztrans function [link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ztrans.html?refresh=true) shows it return a function. Are you doing symbolic computations?

Comment: yes, it should return a function (z).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've got two problems: calculating `f(x) = x XOR 16`, and then computing the z-transform of the result.

Here's an (updated) z-transform function which will work on a defined x optionally an arbitrary `n` vector (with the default assumption that `n` starts at 0 and goes up by one for each value of `x`). It now returns a function that can be used to evaluate various z values:

```
ztransform = function(x, n = seq_along(x) - 1) {
    function(z) sum(x * z ^ -n)
}

my_z_trans = ztransform(x = 0:100, n = 0:100)
my_z_trans(z = 1)
# [1] 5050
my_z_trans(z = 2)
# [1] 2
my_z_trans(z = 3)
# [1] 0.75
```

Comment: n Xor 16 is not a problem for me I can calculate it . Yes, main question is z-transform. i have noticed in your answer you are using z=16. It's not . The expected answer should be a function of (z).

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question with *short* sample input and output? Is the goal a function object so that you could do `my_z_trans = ztransform(x, n)` and then later evaluate the result for any value of z, e.g., `my_z_trans(5)`?

Comment: @SimpleNEasy Changed it to match the behavior I described. Not clear in your question why you are spelling out each term on `n` when they all just get summed.

Comment: @SimpleNEasy one last bug fix: forgot to remove `z` from the arg list of `ztransform`. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks. I was trying to follow the general definition. Forgot to change it after update !.